# Reverse Engineering Serial Protocol

Tags: serial-port, reverse-engineering, rs485

This is quite long, but if you're into reverse engineering and know stuff about serial protocols, please bear with me. I have the questions at the end once I've laid out all the data and what have I done already.

I have this project ongoing where I try to get the data out of my boiler and store it for monitoring purposes. Boiler it self has a relay board with RS485 connection, that connection is meant to be used with a room controller and is on a same bus than the Boilers own main controller.

I figured out the pins on the relay board as:

- 51 = GND
- 52 = RS485/A
- 53 = RS485/B
- 54 = +5VDC

Then connected the logic analyzer and got the data out. I have two datasets from the logic analyzer, first when the main controller is idle (capture) and a dataset when the main controller is put to info view which displays the temperatures for different sensors in the boiler (capture3).

During both captures, the boiler and the main controller where connected and there is no way for me to get in between these. So I can only see the traffic in the whole bus, but cannot tell who is sending what.

From both datasets, I assumed that the connection is 115200 8n1.

When the boiler is in "idle" it sends this some pingpong "A3 FD" that gets reply "00" and at times there is some status sent, that I assume is from the relay board.

```
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.038605 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.039344 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.039951 A3 24 09 A2 80 04 83 18 01 00 08 FF
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.054151 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.054892 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.100784 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.101527 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.162962 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.163702 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.225138 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.225878 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.287315 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.288054 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.349493 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.350235 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.411669 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.412407 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.473849 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.474591 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.536025 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.536764 00
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.537370 A3 24 09 A2 80 04 83 10 01 00 08 BB
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.551570 A3 FD
    2021-05-25T05:19:57.552313 00
```

Then, when the main controller is put to info view, I can see packets starting with 07 to appear in to the bus. I think I can also identify request-response pattern. So I assume things starting with 07 are from the main controller when it's requesting data.

```
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.475221 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.476051 00
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.547727 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.548452 07 A2 81 81 68 AA 04 00
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.596947 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.597668 00
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.598231 A3 24 09 A2 80 83 68 81 AA 8E 03 6E
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.599577 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.600422 00
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.672082 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.672808 07 A2 81 81 69 AA 05 66
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.673858 A3 24 09 A2 80 04 83 98 00 00 08 2B
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.675972 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.676702 00
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.677308 A3 24 09 A2 80 83 69 81 AA F3 00 F0
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.678559 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.679396 00
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.734260 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.734979 07 A2 81 81 6A AA 06 CC
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.783478 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.784215 00
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.784780 A3 24 09 A2 80 83 6A 81 AA FF 7F 50
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.786109 A3 FD
    2021-05-26T05:27:41.786961 00
```

What I have already noted:

Requests

- First 4 bytes are always the same
- 5th byte is a rolling number (maybe sensor id?)
- 6th byte is always AA (some sort of separator or command?)
- 7th byte is a rolling number between 01-09

Responses

- First 6 bytes are always the same
- 7th byte is always the same as the requests 5th byte
- bytes 8 and 9 are always 81 AA
- Last 3 bytes change so it could be the data and checksum

I tried to match the responses to the values in the screen during capture:

```
    T01: 23
    T02: 13
    T03: --
    T04: 47
    T05: 88
    T06: 24
    T07: --
    T08: 86
    T09: 59
    T10: 20
```

I also assume that the numbers are rounded in the screen and most likely the data is transferred as 16bit signed integer as temperatures (at least outside T2) can be negative.

Questions that I have:

- Do you agree with the 115200 8n1 ?
- Does someone recognize the protocol ?
- Can someone see something else that I'm not seeing ?
- Suggestions what to do next to get this thing cracked :)

I've put here all the capture data (Saleae Logic), parsed packets and the request response pairs I though I recognized.
[Data in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DVdQj0L9fVuRq2wIfar4jdh-YPx73B0O?usp=sharing).

Note that on the capture data:
Channel 0 = RS485/A
Channel 2 = RS485/B

Answer (score 0):

I know, very late to respond, but in case anyone else is looking.

1. Values may be "fixed-point" numbers, so the value will be 2^n times larger than you expected.  A quick way to find the number of places after the "binary blob", or bits for the fractional part, keep dividing by two (right shifting) until the number seems to be rounded down version of what you see on the display. The numbers in the transfer could be 2, 4, 8, 16 etc times bigger than expected.
2. Values may be decicelcius/centicelsius, so 10 or 100 times what you expect.
3. Values might be BCD - binary coded decimal, each 4 bit chunk mapping to a digit. This used to be common in RTCs (real time clocks) and maybe numeric displays, but is probably not used in this case.
4. The system will always communicate in °F or °C, probably °C. The communications units will probably not change, even if you change how it is displayed.
5. I haven't looked at your SAL file from the Saleae, but I was recently talking to someone else about a boiler interface, and their trace showed what looked like a wake-up stream once a second just before the command and response sequence.  The 0xFD packets may be this.
6. You are looking at the Hex values, what does it look like in decimal? Anything leap out at you?
7. If you can access the boards, you may find the RS-485 transceiver. The TX EN signal should toggle when the unit is sending, this will tell you the outbound from the inbound.
8. I've noticed RS-485 modules may have "unique personality" in so far as the differential between A and B may be larger from one node than the other.  It won't show which is which, but you will have more chance of seeing a difference, and infer from content.
9. Industrial controller with RS-485?  Maybe it's MODBUS, but that's a wild guess.